# Saying 'Congratulations' on new year and someone's birthday; the act of saying "happy new year/birthday" ; "happy new year in advance"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, functions

I used to think we use *congratulations* for achievements but I recently came across an occassion when a native speaker said "congratulations" when he heard it's someone's birthday.

1. Can we use *congratulations* for birthdays or that person just made it up?!
2. What about new year? Can we use *congratulations* for new year's occassion, too? Think of this:
   I say

> *"Today is our New Year's Day"*

can you say,

> *"Congratulations, didn't know that"*

The following questions are a bit different from the previous ones but they're related to new year and stuff.

3. When you say *"congratulations"* to someone, you **congratulate** them on an achievement (at least I'm sure about this usage). When you say, *"happy new year"* or *"happy birthday"* what do you do exactly? (I suppose it's not congratulating!)
4. There is a week left to the New Year and I want to say *"happy new year"* to someone maybe because I know I won't see that person anymore by the end of the holidays (in my language we do this because it's polite). What should I say? 
   Is *"happy new year in advance"* a good phrasing? If not, what are better replacements for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard *congratulations* used in birthday greetings, or in wishing someone a happy new year, but it's generally intended to be somewhat humorous.

When I've heard it used, the implication has been: *Congratulations! You made it through another year.* Put another way: *It's been a whole year and you're still alive. Congratulations.*

Some might consider such "congratulations" to be morbid humor, particularly if the person you are talking to is quite advanced in age.

---

As for saying,

> "Congratulations, I didn't know that."

I'd be careful with that one. It sounds like a sarcastic remark given to someone who has just stated something obvious.

---

As for:

> "Happy new year in advance"

that sounds normal and idiomatic to me. Another more casual way you could say the same thing is:

> "Have a happy new year!"

By putting the "Have a" at the start of the remark, you're acknowledging that the new year is coming soon but is still a little ways away.

Comment: Thanks J.R. so that native speaker was humorous. What about the 3rd question? Is it 'congratulating'?

Comment: Azad - One might call it [_well-wishing_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well-wishing). The remark itself might also be called a _seasonal greeting_, or a form of [salutation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/salutation). I think those are better terms than "congratulating".